# SELECT all ancestors with single query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have following table in PostgreSQL and need to get all ancestors of person with given ID.
It is also necessary to be able to distinguish father and mother from the results.

```
Person table - has about 1M rows, schema looks like this:
+-----+--------+--------+
| id  | father | mother |
+-----+--------+--------+
|   1 |      2 |      3 |
|   2 |      4 |      5 |
|   3 |      6 |      7 |
|   4 |      8 |      9 |
|   5 |     10 |     11 |
| ... |    ... |    ... |
| ... |    ... |    ... |
+-----+--------+--------+
```

Currently I am doing queries in a loop, getting single row per each person.

Is it possible to get all ancestors in single query (or 2 queries)?

Example result for querying id 2:

```
+----+--------+--------+
| id | father | mother |
+----+--------+--------+
|  2 |      4 |      5 |
|  4 |      8 |      9 |
|  5 |     10 |     11 |
+----+--------+--------+
```

Comment: Edit your question and show the results that you want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
WITH recursive ParentOf (id, father, mother )
AS
(
-- Anchor query
    SELECT id, father, mother 
    FROM test
    WHERE id = ? -- e.g. 2
    UNION ALL
-- Recursive query
    SELECT t.id, t.father, t.mother
    FROM test t
    INNER JOIN ParentOf
    ON t.id = ParentOf.father OR t.id = ParentOf.mother
)
-- Statement that executes the CTE
SELECT id, father, mother 
FROM ParentOf;
```

Answer (score 1):

THIS ANSWERS THE ORIGINAL VERSION OF THE QUESTION.

For this purpose, it is easiest to unpivot your table with one column per parent.  Then use a recursive CTE to get all parents.

The code looks like this:

```
with recursive t as (
      select 1 as id, 2 as father, 3 as mother union all
      select 2, 4, 5 union all
      select 3, 6, 7 union all
      select 4, 8, 9 union all
      select 5, 10, 11
     ),
     parents as (
      select id, father as parent from t union all
      select id, mother from t
     ),
     cte as (
      select p.id, p.parent
      from parents p
      where id = 2  -- or whatever id you want
      union all
      select cte.id, p.parent
      from cte join
           parents p
           on cte.parent = p.id
     )
select *
from cte;
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/21156) is a SQL Fiddle.

Comment: Could you post a version without specific IDs in query?
Actual used table has millions of rows.
  
I also need to be able to distinguish between mother and father in the results.

Comment: @stkxchng . . . Your question, as clearly stated in the first sentence, is "I have following table in PostgreSQL and need to get all ancestors of person with given ID."  If you have a different question, please ask another question.  Changing the question after it has been answered is rude, because it can lead to downvotes.  But, you can remove the `where` clause in the last CTE and see if that does what you want.

Comment: I apologize, I have edited the question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

If I got it correctly,
you could just use `JOIN` or a simple `IN()`

For the `IN` it would be something like :

```
SELECT 
    p.id, 
    p.father,
    p.mother 
FROM person p
WHERE 
p.id = 2
OR p.id IN (SELECT father FROM person WHERE id = 2)
OR p.id IN (SELECT mother FROM person WHERE id = 2)
```

this would give you :

```
| id | father | mother |
|----|--------|--------|
|  2 |      4 |      5 |
|  4 |      8 |      9 |
|  5 |     10 |     11 |
```

For the `JOIN`you could do self-join on columns to pair it with id. just like this :

```
SELECT 
      x.id as id, 
      x.father as father, 
      x.mother as mother
FROM person p
LEFT JOIN person x ON x.id = p.id OR x.id = p.father OR x.id = p.mother
WHERE 
  p.id = 2
```

this will also gives you the same results.

From there, you can use more conditions under WHERE clause to have a proper results.

[Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/50c45/79)